# Helpful sidebar content is down below

Tags: feature-request, design, sidebar, responsive-design

Currently, when the window becomes too narrow, the whole right sidebar is just appended *below* the whole main column.

[image]

That is bad for two reasons.

1. Parts that are immediately related to the top and/or actually useful are too far below.

   - asked/viewed/active stats
   - linked/related questions
   - featured on meta (maybe)
   - similar questions, how to ask (Ask Question)
2. The different sidebar boxes do not utilize the horizontal space available to them.

#### Concrete proposals

- Put asked/viewed/active stats under the title, with subtle formatting.
- Put linked and related questions directly below the question, as fold-outs.
- Put "Featured on Meta" (those may be important) at the very top; make this box dismissable.
  Hot Meta can remain down below.
- Make remaining boxes share "lines" if possible.

Comment: Very nice proposals.

Answer (score 3):

> - Put asked/viewed/active stats under the title, with subtle formatting.

This seems to [have been addressed in the latest build](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331346/295232). This is how the current question looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: I think it was first tested on meta.SO for a little and then released throughout the network.

Comment: Yes, that's standard procedure for changes like that. MSE and/or MSO are updated somewhat ahead of the rest of the network.

Comment: Pretty sure it was just MSO here. Also, this standard procedure is often omitted. :D