# Display post asked/viewed/active info directly beneath the question on mobile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, mobile-web, responsive-design

When I mention asked/viewed/active, I mean this little bit seen at the top of the sidebar:

> [image: “asked 8 years 9 months ago. viewed 313 times. active today.]

This information can be substantially relevant for people dropping in to moderate or curate a question. The “active today” bit also provides a link to the most recently modified post on the page.

On desktop this information is provided conveniently at the top right, but on the mobile breakpoint we have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page beneath the very last answers to find it.

I think it would be for the better to provide this information directly beneath the question on mobile breakpoint. Here's a super basic mockup of what that might look like (the alignment of various elements doesn't look the prettiest, so that's something to work on):

> [image]

Comment: update: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331349/300177

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be live as of now. The sidebar widget has been removed and the 'Asked', 'Active' (if applicable) and 'Viewed' information is now directly beneath the question on all screen sizes. This is how the current question looks like:

[image]

Comment: Why was this changed for the desktop view as well? I get that this may be useful on mobile, yet on desktop it's irritating.