# Add link styling to the latest activity link in the question stats

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, hyperlinks, question-statistics

With the new design of putting the question stats under the post title, it's not obvious at all the latest activity time is a clickable link.  The current style blends in with the non-link labels on either side:

[image: The "today" part of "Active: today" is actually a link but doesn't look like one.]

This is even true if the link has been visited. The color of the "today" text remains black (at least on MSE) as if it was just label text.

Can we make this component more obvious that it's actually a clickable link?

Comment: @AaronShekey how is this by design? This is asking to change the design, not reporting a bug.

Comment: @Stormblessed haha_classic.jpg

Comment: @Suvitruf I'm confused

Comment: @Stormblessed sorry. It's just kinda funny. It's not the first time, when I see behavior like this from mods/SE employees (:

Comment: @Stormblessed: "*how is this by design?*" It means that they *want* it that way. Why, I have no idea, but that's what they're communicating.

Comment: @Nicol but by design seems to be for bugs. Shouldn’t this be declined instead?

Comment: @Stormblessed: "Declined" would simply mean "we're not doing it". "By design" says that, while also saying that they want it this way. It provides useful information.