# Post with only 1 flag allows you to scroll down, but not up

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

When looking at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331349/369802), a flag showed up underneath it, and a scrollbar (which usually means there's another flag). But there's only 1 flag, and when I scroll down, I enter into an endless void of empty grey:

[image]

And once you do that, you're stuck in that void: Scrolling up again doesn't work.

I'm only seeing this on this one post though, the other flagged posts on MSE seem fine.

Comment: You can click and drag on the scrollbar marker thing, which *eventually* gets you back - see my previous (deleted) comment for an example of this - its a mod only view so for the eyes of those in the know only ;)

Comment: Oh my goodness! This exposes so much of the mod UI, I wonder what use I have for it.