# Close button for 'join this community' banner is too low contrast

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

The close button on the sign up banner when visiting a site that you're not a part of is too difficult to see, not only does the low contrast make it harder to see, but it's also near other "shapes" (pluses, triangles, dots, circles) of a similar colour, which causes it to blend in somewhat contextually as well:

[image]

[image]

This becomes even more apparent when viewing a site on a larger screen:

[image]

Can we bump up the contrast to make it easier to see? And potentially move it upwards a bit so that it comfortably sits slightly further away from the other content?

Comment: There's a close button??

Comment: Also, it seems like some other buttons are affected like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeD4g.png) (barely visible when hovered).

Comment: When the cursor is over the button, the colour changes.

Comment: @RandomPerson-onstrike Yes, it does, but it should really be visible without having to find it first or without moving your mouse all over until you see it light up, so it's not totally clear what your point is.

Comment: @bobeyt6isstricken LOL, never noticed that button either until now. Terrible design. Or not... the goal is to not have users close it, so I believe it's on purpose.

Comment: This is almost certainly an unintended result of some UI changes over time, judging from Wayback Machine archives of the MSE home page on January 1, 2023 vs. the start of this month (July 1) vs. now. (Given that it seems like this particular issue started between [July 24](https://web.archive.org/web/20230724153821/https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and [July 26](https://web.archive.org/web/20230726192757/https://meta.stackexchange.com/), it might be related to the changes made as part of [Colors update: A more detailed look](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390761/335251).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with the banner using dark themed colors but the buttons still using light themed colors. We've applied the proper overrides and the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Looks much better now, thanks!