# "Viewed 1 times" bug still around after 10 years

Tags: discussion, plurals

Almost a decade ago now, somebody asked about this: ["viewed 1 times"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

All the replies to that question/bug report are of a very hostile kind.

Why has this bug not been fixed for this long? One of the replies appears to be mentioning that it has been fixed, but it has not, as of today, 2019-08-20.

What gives? A site as "polished" (over-engineered, one might say) as this really has no excuse whatsoever to let such a bug be for 10 years after it was pointed out.

PS: No, I'm not making some kind of "joke". I'm serious.

Comment: Is this happening on a question page, where it shows the number of views [immediately under the question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331349/why-are-the-sidebar-stats-for-a-question-now-under-the-title)? If so, I *suspect* that this is a regression brought about by that recent change (rather than it not really [being fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119416/185080)).

Comment: Maybe it is me but is it really needed to make your question read like an accusation  instead of a factual bug report?

Comment: Is the actual question *"Why has this bug not been fixed for this long?"* or is this a bug report?

Comment: I'm asking why it has not been fixed, yeah. And at the same time, re-reporting the bug.