# Can we have a little more accessibility with the stats below question titles?

Tags: support, design, accessibility, question-statistics

The question stats (when asked, when last active, and views) were recently moved into the main part of the page from the right column, which is [a big help for some use cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314445/162102).  I just have one small request:

[image: screenshot of new layout]

Those fonts are pretty small -- smaller than they were when this information was in the right column.  That would probably be ok (meaning I'll probably get used to it) if we had the information in tooltips.  We do have dates in tooltips (though sometimes "2 days ago" is more useful than "2019-07-23 03:12:11Z"), but there's no tooltip for the view count.

I'd personally prefer it if we could bump up the font one notch, though I know that some people think it's already too prominent.  One might point out that this is the same font size as the links below a post (share, close, flag, etc), *but* those are fixed text and always in the same order, so you don't need as much visual acuity to use them as to use arbitrary text of the same size.

Worse comes to worst, I'll (get some inspector-navigation help and) add some more CSS overrides to my browser to make the font bigger.  But on the theory that I'm not the only person with this problem, I figured I'd ask if there are other ways to address my problem -- at least a tooltip on the count?

(I do think this information is in the right place on the page.  It's helpful to be clued in *before diving into a question* that it was asked 8 years ago and nobody's touched it for 6 years, so the information here might well be obsolete.  And too often I see an interesting question that I think I can answer, read it carefully, and only *then* see that it was asked years ago by a now-deleted user.  Hints up front about the state of the page are useful.)

Comment: Is that just the screenshot or could the contrast also use some notch?

Comment: @rene that's the screenshot; vast expanses of bright white pixels hurt my eyes, so I have a userscript that changes white backgrounds to light brown.  (I realize that "light" is in the eye of the beholder too; there's this complicated dance of monitor calibration, room lighting, browser tuning, and sometimes OS settings that all affect how readable something is.  You can't see monitor and lighting settings in the screenshot. :-) )

Comment: Ah, thanks. I remembered you used a special setup but I didn't account for that background. I was clicking through all the sites you have an account on to find the site with that color scheme ...

Comment: @rene FWIW that screenshot is from The Workplace Meta I believe which has a white background.

Comment: The problem is that, the bigger the font, the more space it takes up. And we already have people complaining that the "pretty small" font is [taking up too much room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331370/164572). Any increase in size only makes that issue worse.

Comment: @NicolBolas on the other hand, if satisfying my request costs another couple pixels and that's a problem, they could take those pixels from the space between the header and title -- plenty of extra space there.  My request could be satisfied in a height-neutral way; the issue of the 12 pixels from having this at all is separate.

Comment: the "*Asked:*", "*Active:*" and "*Viewed:*" need to be in *italics*, too, to distinguish them better from the data that follows. Otherwise it's non-separated blur. the different shades of grey are insufficient, borderline non-noticeable.

Comment: @WillNess italics makes things harder to read, especially at small sizes.  I'll bet they can come up with some way to make it clear that this line is neither the title nor the body without resorting to that.

Comment: hmm, for me it's easier (not the whole line of italic text, but when only some words in it are in italics). they could use a different-looking font, like Comic. also can play with the font's width (boldness).